# Caixa de texto entrada de texto a direita

Tags: javascript, html, css

Em uma caixa que o texto está alinhado para a direita, como eu faço para que quando focar a caixa de texto independente do lugar o cursor de escrita vá para a direita?

quero que ao clicar em um input do tipo text onde está inserido um valor decimal o cursos sempre vá para o último caractere à direita

Comment: Se o campo está alinhado à direita, o cursor fica sempre à direita. Não estou entendendo a pergunta, pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Não estou a entender a pergunta. Queres por uma caixa de texto para a direita quando ela já esta na direita? Foi o que entendi

Comment: o campo é entrada de valor decimal, quando o usuário clicar no meio do valor por exemplo antes da virgula eu quero o cursor de escrita vá para o final do canto direito

Comment: Você quer que ao clicar em um input do tipo *text* onde está inserido um valor decimal o cursos sempre vá para o último caractere à direita. é isso?

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei a resposta em outra pergunta no Stack Overflow (em inglês). Veja se serve:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368750/how-to-set-the-cursor-position-at-the-end-of-a-string-in-a-text-field-using-jque

```
$('#foo').focus(function() {
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
        this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length, this.value.length);
    } else if (this.createTextRange) {
        // internet explorer
        var range = this.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveStart('character', this.value.length);
        range.moveEnd('character', this.value.length);
        range.select();
    }
});
```

Comment: Mesmo que a resposta não seja sua vou te dar um certo, porque você trouxe ela até a mim

Comment: Também vi isso, mas testei e não funcionou - http://jsfiddle.net/8xWtb/

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="ltr(this)" />

function ltr (el)
{   
    if (el.setSelectionRange) {
        el.setSelectionRange(0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse é um parâmetro para que a direção do texto no input seja direita-para-esquerda. O que o usuário quer é que o cursor do texto vá para a direita, mas a direção do texto continua sendo esquerda-para-direita.

Comment: é bem isso mesmo, mas eu queria que ele fosse para a direita